# Books to get prepared before self studying Artificial Intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, discrete-mathematics

I want to study Artificial Intelligence from *Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach* by *Russell* and *Norvig*, in the mid-year vacation. I want to get prepared before diving into the book so I decided to review some relevant subjects like Discrete Mathematics. I know there is a good book for Discrete Mathematics by *Kenneth. H. Rosen* and bought it. But I don't know about any other books to read before studying AI.

Can someone give me book suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you just read the book you want to read (*AIMA*) and look up anything you find you need to know.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I'll try to read AIMA first but I'm not sure my background  is enough. I hope it is. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probability theory is also extremely important for artificial intelligence. A textbook I very much recommend on this subject is [Probability, Statistics, and Stochastic Processes](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470889748) by Olofsson and Andersson.

Many areas of artificial intelligence, particularly those concerning image processing of some sort, also make good use of linear algebra. For this, I recommend [Linear Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0130084514) by Spence, Insel, and Friedberg, or [Linear Algebra Done Right](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982582) by Axler if you want a more pure mathematics approach.